# Filter contentresolver query by date and time - Android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'm using the "MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" to query for photos stored on the sd-card. Now I only want photos that were added after some specific date. I'm using the "contentResolver.query()" method  to query but I don't understand how to filter by Date_ADDED or DATE_MODIFIED. Can this be done?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Date date = ...;
contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
        null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">?", 
        new String[]{"" + date},
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
```

That will find all images with DATE_ADDED after the specified date, sorted by DATE_ADDED from most recent to oldest.

Comment: what is the difference between DATE_TAKEN and DATE_ADDED ? is DATE_TAKEN about when the image was taken? is DATE_ADDED about when it was added to the device's media DB ?

Comment: Which Date is this? The java.util.Date, or java.sql.Date?